# How to hide some declared Methods in ASMX file in Web Service C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api

i have one doubt in Web Service / WCF
i'm creating the service and it's having 10 methods respectively

test1() , Program1(int age),Describe1(), DisplayAge(string name),,SimilarInterest(),ServiceCall(), Hide(), Difference(), WebService() and Help()

now after hosting this service in asmx only the below methods should display. others should not need to display. 
DisplayAge(string name),,SimilarInterest(),ServiceCall() only these three should display when i call the http://URL.asmx?wsdl
the other 7 methods should not need to display in asmx wsdl file .how to do that?

Comment: Make them private?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in XML Web Service(ASMX), this should not work if you want the service to be both invoked and not shown in the WSDL. Either using private decorated methods or removing the [WebMethod] attribute causes the method to no longer be invoked. If in WCF we can implement authentication, authorization that individual methods cannot be invoked, or simply not expose metadata. But we cannot hide the specified method (but can be called by the outside world).
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/533e0361-e9e0-400b-a7b2-f098a9ef3e75/how-to-prevent-web-method-from-showing-on-service-description-page?forum=asmxandxml
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.